# how can i set VS Code debugger for react & node App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code

Actually i have an application which have node and react projects.
and both projects are handle by another package.json.

So i need to run the complete app through debugger but when i run from common package.json it runs the app but debugger is not approchable.

I tried with **launch with npm** as well but didn't get any luck.

[image]